# Horizontal strip with content align

Tags: html, css

Can anybody help me with the following thing.

I want my strip to align in the following way(image).
[image]

But anyhow fail to achieve it.

My code:

```css
.service-band{
 background-color: #01A89E;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.service-band .ellipse{
 width: 20%;
 padding: 0.5%;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 margin: auto;
 border-radius: 30px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.circletag {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
 padding:10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;   
  position:relative;
}
img {
  padding:5px;
  height: 60px;
  width:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container service-band">
   <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-sm-4 ellipse" style = "margin:auto"><font color = "white">+91 xxxxxxxxx</font></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 circletag img-responsive" id="nay">
     <img class ="img-responsive" src = "https://pro-rankedboost.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Togepi-Pokemon-Go.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-sm-4 ellipse" ><font color = "white">Get a Quote</font></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

[Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgMGbO)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set parent element to **display:flex**

```
<div class = "container service-band">
            <div class = "row">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <div class = "col-sm-4 ellipse" style = "margin:auto">
          <font color = "white">+91 xxxxxxxxx</font></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 circletag img-responsive" id="nay">
                    <img class ="img-responsive" src = "https://pro-rankedboost.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Togepi-Pokemon-Go.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-4 ellipse" ><font color = "white">Get a Quote</font></div>
          </div>
        </div>
            </div>
```

Add class **d-flex**

```
.d-flex{
  display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display: inline-block` to inline your elements.

I also added a fixed margin-bottom of 40px.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZrLjN

Answer (score 0):

Lokks like you are using bootsrap classes. You may use [boostrap4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) wich comes along the flex model and add a max-width to your image :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgEjNE

```css
.service-band {
  background-color: #01A89E;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.service-band .ellipse {
  padding: 0.5%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.circletag {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
                               max-width: 80px!important;/* !important only seems necessary within the snippet on SO , you may avoid it*/
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container service-band">
  <div class="row d-flex ">
    <div class="col-sm-4 ellipse" style="margin:auto">
      <font color="white">+91 xxxxxxxxx</font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 circletag img-responsive" id="nay">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://pro-rankedboost.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Togepi-Pokemon-Go.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 ellipse">
      <font color="white">Get a Quote</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```